# Download file from API server using URLConnection in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, download, httpurlconnection

I want to download a file into my library using URLConnection.
The size of the picture stored in the server is about 16mb, but the size of the saved picture is 84B.
There seems to be an error while reading the buffer, can you tell me what kind of error it is?

```
    binding.signDownloadBtn.setOnClickListener {
        val userId = binding.userIdText.text.toString()
        val filetype = "user"
        val fileSeparation = "sign"

        Thread {
            val spec = "myurl/${userId}/${filetype}/${fileSeparation}"

            val outputDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS
            var `is`: InputStream? = null
            var os: FileOutputStream? = null

            try {
                val url = URL(spec)
                val conn = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection

                conn.requestMethod = "GET"
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;utf-8")
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json")
                conn.setRequestProperty("token", user_token)
                conn.setRequestProperty("sysCd", sysCd)
                conn.connectTimeout = 1500

                println("responseCode ${conn.responseCode}")

                if (conn.responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    var fileName = ""
                    val disposition = conn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition")
                    val contentType = conn.contentType

                    if (disposition != null) {
                        val target = "filename="
                        val index = disposition.indexOf(target)

                        if (index != -1) {
                            fileName =
                                disposition.substring(index + target.length)
                            fileName =
                                fileName.replace("\"", "")
                        }

                        println("Content-Type = $contentType")
                        println("Content-Disposition = $disposition")
                        println("fileName = $fileName")

                        `is` = conn.inputStream
                        os = FileOutputStream(File(outputDir, fileName))

                        val BUFFER_SIZE = 4096
                        var bytesRead: Int
                        val buffer = ByteArray(BUFFER_SIZE)
                        while (`is`.read(buffer).also { bytesRead = it } != -1) {
                            os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                        }
                        os.close()
                        `is`.close()
                    }

                    println("File downloaded")
                } else {
                    println("No file to download. Server replied HTTP code: ${conn.responseCode}")
                }
                conn.disconnect()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println("An error occurred while trying to download a file.")
                e.printStackTrace()
                try {
                    `is`?.close()
                    os?.close()
                } catch (e1: IOException) {
                    e1.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }.start()
    }
```

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: just have a try with flush() method instead  close()

Comment: Have you considered using a more modern HTTP client API, such as OkHttp?

Comment: `I want to download a file into my library` ? Into a library? I would think into a storage location of the used device.

Comment: If you have errors you should tell us which ones.

Comment: You do not have to set request method and all those request properties.

Comment: 1. I wrote down the request method and properties because it is a required item when requesting from the API server. If you don't write it down, a 500 error pops up.
2. I think the translator misinterpreted the word library. Cell phone storage is correct.

Comment: 3. I'll try that library ^^

Comment: 4. I changed it to flush() instead of close(), but the method does not work in InputStream(is.flush()) but works in OutputStream. So I flushed only the OutputStream.
"java.io.IOException: closed" error occurs. The error code is " while (`is`.read(buffer).also { bytesRead = it } != -1) {
                            os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                        }" part.

Comment: 4-1. I just solved the "java.io.IOException: closed" error. But using flush() still downloads an incomplete image file

Comment: I found the problem. When I first uploaded the file from the smartphone, the wrong file was going. The basic information has been uploaded, but the image itself seems not to have been transmitted.